# Pasting Text From Excel to Word in Specific Locations VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to place variables that I have already established (In this case the variable is QN_number) into a word document in specific locations, I have done this in the past except I placed an entire table into word so the code was different. I have not been able to find a way to past using the variable names directly which would be preferred instead having to reference a range each time. Also the method I am using now is not working well as it does paste in the proper location, but it pastes the words associated with the variable as a selection box that can be moved and resized. I would like is pasted just like any other text in the document. Here is the code that I am using right now. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Sub Export_Excel_To_Word()

'Connect to M-Word
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = New Word.Application
wordApp.Visible = True
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document

i = 0

'Exits loop when QN#s are finished
Do
If Cells(i + 2, 2) = "" Then
Exit Do
Else: End If


'Opens the Template Word Document For Discus Complaints
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(File_Name)


 'Places the QN# in the Word Document
 With Worksheets("Data").Cells(i + 2, 2)
 .Copy
wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute "Complaint Description:" '***Places after a specfic word
wordApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=-1, Extend:=wdMove '***Moves the placement up a line
wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
'wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add
wordApp.Selection.Paste
End With
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question eventually

First define your variables then use the following code

```
'Places the QN# in the Word Document
wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute "Complaint Description:" '***Places after a specfic word
wordApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=-1, Extend:=wdMove '***Moves the placement up a line
wordApp.Selection.TypeText (QN_number)
```